# php not saving files

Tags: php, linux, file, permissions

php isn't downloading and saving files. I've got the save location in open_basedir, and when I su to the user httpd runs as I can mkdir and touch files.

> [Wed Nov 03 22:54:00.733144 2021] [php:warn] [pid 203155] [client 192.168.1.11:33844] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for /tmp/tarot/crowley/crowley.zip in /home/www/tarot.php on line 58, referer: https://thechatpit.org/tarot.php
> [Wed Nov 03 22:54:00.733341 2021] [php:warn] [pid 203155] [client 192.168.1.11:33844] PHP Warning:  readfile(/tmp/tarot/crowley/crowley.zip): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/tarot.php on line 60, referer: https://thechatpit.org/tarot.php

The mkdir call:

```
$zpath = "/tmp/tarot/".$Deck."/";
if(!file_exists($zpath)){
    mkdir($zpath, 0700, true);
}
```

I've tried it with looser permissions, but they don't seem to help. I've double checked, and /tmp/ is in open_basedir:

> open_basedir = "/usr/share/webapps/:/home/www/:/var/log/:/tmp/:/var/lib/:/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/config/:"

...so yeah, I've been banging my head against this all day and can't seem to find the problem.

More applicable code:

```
    $Deck = $Decks[$_GET['rip']];

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zpath = "/tmp/tarot/".$Deck."/";
    if(!file_exists($zpath)){
        mkdir($zpath, 0700, true);
    }
    $zhandle = $zpath.$Deck.".zip";

    if(!file_exists($zhandle)){
        $zip->open($zhandle, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        for($i=0; $i<78; $i++){
            $url = "https:.gfx.tarot.com/images/site/decks/".$Deck."/full_size/".$i.".jpg";
            $proxy = "192.168.1.69:9050";
            $cURL = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            $tarotcard = curl_exec($cURL);
            curl_close($cURL);

            $file = $zpath."/".$i.".jpg";
            if(is_writable($file)){
                $fhandle = fopen($file, 'wb+');
                fwrite($fhandle, $tarotcard);
                fclose($fhandle);
            }
                
            if(file_exists($file)){
                $zip->addFile($file);
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        $zip->close();
    
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('ContentDisposition: attachment; filename='.$Deck.'.zip');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zhandle));
    
        readfile($zhandle);
    }

    exit();
}
```

Comment: You've got an error on line 58 and and error on line 60 but the source you posted can't explain both. Which is 58 and which is 60?

Comment: Check for sticky bits in /tmp

Comment: Line 58:

>header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zhandle));

...and 60:

>readfile($zhandle);

It happens after zipping the downloads and sending it to the client. I end up with an empty zip file

Comment: drwxrwxrwt -- and that t looks suspicious, thanks

Comment: ...and chmod -t /tmp didn't fix it

Comment: /tmp/tarot is one of the directories not being created by the mkdir call:

```
mkdir("/tmp/tarot/".$Deck."/", 0700, true);
```

Comment: Just did, no changes crowley/. and crowley.zip are still not showing up

Comment: From the shell, yes. php's the one not behaving

Comment: I have experienced this before. It is almost always a permission problem. Add defensive/debug code at every step. After `mkdir` check to see if the directory was added.

Comment: I added a line with if(!file_exists($zpath)){exit('could not create '.$zpath);} -- now it doesn't exit, but there's still nothing in /tmp